# Conditionally render a div with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, conditional-statements, logic

I am trying to build a quiz which when the user chooses a selection and submits the answer the notification div displays whether choice is correct or not. I have got this logic working however what is happening is the div is disappearing each time the next question is answered. I want to keep the previous question result on the screen and lock the user out of answering the question again and show the correct answer.

Here is what I have so far:

```
                  <div
                    class="container"
                    v-for="options in quiz"
                    v-bind:key="options.quizId"
                  >
                    <h3>{{ options.question }}</h3>
                    <div
                      class="control"
                    >
                      <label class="radio">
                        <input
                          type="radio"
                          :value="options.op1"
                          v-model="selectedAnswer"
                        />
                        {{ options.op1 }}
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control">
                      <label class="radio">
                        <input
                          type="radio"
                          :value="options.op2"
                          v-model="selectedAnswer"
                        />
                        {{ options.op2 }}
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control">
                      <label class="radio">
                        <input
                          type="radio"
                          :value="options.op3"
                          v-model="selectedAnswer"
                        />
                        {{ options.op3 }}
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control">
                      <label class="radio">
                        <input
                          type="radio"
                          :value="options.op4"
                          v-model="selectedAnswer"
                        />
                        {{ options.op4 }}
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control mt-4" >
                      <button class="button is-link" @click="call(options.id)">
                        Submit
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <template v-if="options.id === quizId">
                      <template v-if="quizResult == 'correct'">
                         <template v-if="correctAnswer">
                        <div class="notification is-success mt-4">
                          Correct. Well done!
                        </div>
                        </template>
                        <br />
                      
                      </template>
                      <template v-if="quizResult == 'incorrect'">
                        <div class="notification is-danger mt-4">
                          Incorrect. Please try again.
                        </div>
                        <br />
                      </template>
                    </template>
                  </div>

                                </div>
                          </div>
                        </div> <br>
                      </section>
                         </div>
                        </div>

                  <!-- <hr /> -->
                </template>
```

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      course: {},
      lessons: [],
      comments: [],
      activeLesson: null,
      errors: [],
      showModalFlag1: false,
      okPressed1: false,
      quiz: {},
      questionIndex: 0,
      loading: true,
      quizId: null,
      selectedAnswer: "",
      quizResult: null,
      correctAnswer: false,
      userScore: {
        username: '',
        lesson_id: '',
        lesson_score: '',
      },
      images: [
        {
          photo: "",
        },
      ],
      comment: {
        name: "",
        content: "",
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {

    call(id){
      this.submitQuiz(id);
      console.log('checkid@call',id)
    },
    submitQuiz(e) {
      console.log('check-id@submit', e)
      const quizArray = this.quiz;
      const choice = this.selectedAnswer;
      console.log('chosen: ', choice)

      const result = quizArray.filter( obj => obj.op1 === choice || obj.op2 === choice || 
                                      obj.op3 === choice || obj.op4 === choice)[0];
      console.log('result',result.id);

      for (const prop in result) {
          if ( result.hasOwnProperty(prop) ) {
            if (result.id == e) {
              this.quizId = result.id;
              if (choice == result.answer) {
                  this.quizResult = "correct";
                  this.correctAnswer = true;
                  
              }
         if(choice !== result.answer){
            this.quizId = result.id;
            this.quizResult = "incorrect";
         }
          }
        }
    }
    

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have another div or in your notification div to display last answered question.
You can either have a new object that gets overwritten each time you answer correctly or track the index of your loop and use the value of index - 1 to get last answered question. Add a check if index !== 0.

To get index of your loop in html do: v-for="(options, ) in quiz

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing conditions with inner conditions for the correct answer notification. So if your `quizId` is the next one, the outer condition already fails.

It's likely you have an array with questions and thus have an index for the current question. You could save a property a property on that index that shows if the question is correct, so your condition can be extended to also look back for the previous question

Something like this (pseudo code)

```
<template v-if="showCorrectMsg">
  Good!
  ...
```

and then have a computed `showCorrectMsg` method something like this (pseudo code):

```
if (  questions[currentIndex].quizResult == 'correct' || 
      ( currentIndex > 0 && questions[currentIndex - 1].quizResult == 'correct' ) 
   ) return true;

return false;
```

So for this to work you will have to store that flag on each answer given (again, pseudo code):

```
questions[currentIndex].quizResult = [ theAnswer == theRightAnswer ] ? 'correct' : 'wrong';
```

Comment: No, I have one object with nested object arrays containing question, answer, options and id. When the user chooses an option and submits the submit() method loops through the object and returns the array based off the id.

Comment: The structure of the object is not so important. You can still save a flag for the correct answer and then have your condition check if the current and the previous question was correct.